# Commands continuing on multiple lines

Tags: bash

I have the following with `&&` and `||`.  Because I want to have lines within 80 characters, how can I split this on different lines?  Does always need continuation character `\` ?

```
   (( cval != 1 )) && echo "$k" || { echo "" ; printf '%s\n' "${desc[@]}" ; }
```

Comment: You can split a command anywhere in it by adding a backslash and then entering your line break.

Comment: Also, if you insert a line break somewhere where the command cannot end (e.g. after `&&` or `||`), the backslash isn't needed.

Comment: Do not use `&&` and `||` together like this. Use an `if` statement.

Comment: The fragility of such a construct is what led Python, for example, to introduce `a if b else c` as a robust replacement for `b and a or c`.

Comment: fragility in what sense?

Answer (score 3):

> how can I split this on different lines?

So just literally put newlines after `&&` and `||` and after `{` and *instead* of or after `;`. You can also put comments on separate lines, if you want to.

```
(( cval != 1 )) &&
   echo "$k" ||
   {
       echo ""
       printf '%s\n' "${desc[@]}"
   }
```

But really, `&& ||` are confusing. Strongly consider an if. And `echo ""` - just `echo`.

```
   if (( cval != 1 )); then
      echo "$k"
   else
      echo
      printf '%s\n' "${desc[@]}"
   fi
```

Comment: Not just confusing, but fragile. People using `a && b || c` assume that `b` cannot fail, but if it does, `c` will execute even if `a` succeeded.